# Fragment И TextView как реализовать?

Tags: java, android-fragment, textview

Простите,такой вопрос,создал фрагмент теперь хотелось бы что бы он показывал изменение, статического поля "Моней" в одноименном классе,
      **money_job = (TextView)getActivity().findViewById(R.id.money_job);
            money_job.setText(String.format("%08d%n", money));**
насколько я понял нужен адаптер,но я нуб,и не могу быть уверен,простите за потраченное время.

```js
Разметка.
  <TextView
        android:id="@+id/money_job"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true" />
```

```css
Класс обработчик
public class Money {
   public static int money = 0;

    public void salary1() {
        int min = 80;
        int max = 120;
        Random r = new Random();
        int money1 = r.nextInt(max - min + 1) + min;
        money = money + money1;
    }
```

```html
Класс Фрагмента
import su.mmm.www.bomj.Money;
import su.mmm.www.bomj.R;

import static su.mmm.www.bomj.Money.money;


public class FragmentJob extends Fragment implements View.OnClickListener {
    Money mon = new Money();
    private TextView money_job;
     @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_job, container, false);
        money_job = (TextView)getActivity().findViewById(R.id.money_job);
        money_job.setText(String.format("%08d%n", money));
```

Answer (score 0):

```html
public void vMoney(){
    int j = money;
    money_job = (TextView) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.money_job);
    money_job.setText(String.valueOf(j));}
}
```